# Ajax possible to return resource while it's being loaded?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, comet

Using [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest), I can retrieve a page / file dynamically:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.responseText);
};
request.open("get", "/my_file.txt", true);
request.send();
```

However, the `onload` callback only runs when the entire page is downloaded. There are no methods to return the page bit by bit while it is being loaded. This means that `XMLHttpRequest` does not have access to a huge file until it is loaded entirely.

Is JavaScript able to retrieve the content of files (sent through HTTP **1.0**) while they are being loaded dynamically?

Comment: Sounds interesting... cant wait for the answer. :)

Comment: me too..but I think he need to simulating it somehow because with GET he gets the all content :)

Comment: Hi, look at this link and try to keep from there: [Partial XMLHttpRequest responses](http://friendlybit.com/js/partial-xmlhttprequest-responses/)